# convert python code to JSON format with POSTMAN

Tags: python-3.x, postman

i have used the Postman for converting data into json format.

I have write the below code:

```
def customer_get_meals(request, restaurant_id):
    meals = MealSerializer(
        Meal.objects.filter(restaurant_id = restaurant_id).order_by("-id"),
        many = True,
        context = {"request": request}
    ).data

    return JsonResponse({"meals: meals"})
```

this is url

```
url(r'^restaurant/account/$', views.restaurant_account, name = 'restaurant-account'),
url(r'^restaurant/meal/$', views.restaurant_meal, name = 'restaurant-meal'),
url(r'^restaurant/meal/add/$', views.restaurant_add_meal, name = 'restaurant-add-meal'),
url(r'^restaurant/meal/edit/(?P<meal_id>\d+)/$', views.restaurant_edit_meal, name = 'restaurant-edit-meal'),
```

from rest_framework import serializers
from foodtaskerapp.models import Restaurant, Meal

class MealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
def get_image(self, meal):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    image_url = meal.image.url
    return request.build_absolute_uri(image_url)

class Meta:
    model = Meal
    fields = ("id", "name", "short_description", "image", "price")
```

after all I couldn't get the JSON format in Postman with this massage:
TypeError at /api/customer/meals/2/
In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.